# Как отключить автозакрытие символов в emacs?

Tags: emacs

Как отключиться автозакрытие скобок и других символов для языка С++? Например, при вводе символа "(" вводится автоматом и символ ")". Забыл добавить некоторые детали в самом начале, поэтому подниму вопрос. В комментариях указали установить значения для мода, но проблема в том, что все это я делал, хотя делал посредством: "C-:". По дефолту он отключен. Т.е. проблема не в нем.

Comment: Пропишите `(electric-pair-mode    -1)` в свой `~/.emacs`. (снова включить -- `(electric-pair-mode    1)` (Также читайте ^hf electric-pair-mode))

Comment: Вот полезная для настроек ссылка -- https://habr.com/ru/post/248663/

Comment: Наверное зависит от версии и наверняка от содержимого `.emacs`. Попробуйте с чистым `.emacs` (и напишите, какая у вас версия и ОС). У меня `GNU Emacs 25.2.2` и electric-pair-mode работает, как введенная в `*scratch*`, так  и вызванная через `M-x` (тут она работает в режиме on/off)